# BlackBerry Database file in resources folder

Tags: database, blackberry

I have a database file in my resources folder.
I want to get access to this db file within the application, how can I get to this file path?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you check sqlite sample in the SDK ?
on the sample you can find how to do that :)